# Why is my program not printing the values that I want it to print?

Tags: c++

I'm just playing around with a linked list trying to see how it all works. Why is my program printing 5 for both the head and the tail instead of 4 and 5 respectively?

```
struct Node {

    int n;
    Node *next;

};

class LinkedList {

    public:
        Node *head = NULL;
        Node *tail = NULL;

};

int main() {

    Node N;
    LinkedList L;
    
    L.head = &N;
    L.tail = &N;

    L.head->n = 4;
    L.tail->n = 5;

    cout << L.head->n << endl;
    cout << L.tail->n << endl;

}
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: `L.head` and `L.tail` both point at `N`.   So the assignments `L.head->n` and `L.tail->n` both affect `N.n`.   Assigning any `int` the value `4` and then immediately reassigning the same `int` to have the value `5`, means it ends up with the value `5`.

Comment: you have got one node, it cant hold 2 values

Answer (score 2):

Lets read this line closely:

```
    L.head = &N;
    L.tail = &N;
```

This in english says:

1. The head pointer, points at the node `N`.
2. The tail pointer, points at the node `N`.

So when we do this:

```
    L.head->n = 4;
    L.tail->n = 5;
```

This says:

1. Change `L.head->n` which is `N.n` to 4.
2. Change `L.tail->n` which is`N.n` to 5.

So the head and the tail both point at the same thing. You change that thing to 5, so both return 5.

Comment: @JaMiT yep. You can absolutley edit my posts if you spot stuff like this! I will fix it up, thankyou for the note

Comment: No worries, this post and answer will probably disappear anyway based on the current Question vote :p